# Having issue with SOQL finding newly created records

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

I have a system set up using Twilio to log calls in visualforce.

After each call, it creates a custom Call_Log__c object, with a DialId field set to an arbitrary string eg. 'abc123'

I also have a page which recieves Call Results from Twilio using the action field.  This will create another record with the same DialId.

in the insert trigger for both objects, I have code that searches for the DialId in the other object, and tries to link them.

So when I insert Call_Log__c with DialId 'abc123' it looks for a Twilio_Result__c with DialId 'abc123'
and when I insert Twilio_Result__c with DialId 'abc123' it looks for a Call_Log__c with DialId 'abc123'

This code works perfectly in unit tests, it works most of the time in production, but it rarely works in the sandbox, so on the whole I don't trust it.

Does anybody know why this might be?

Comment: To clarify, both objects are always created with the correct DialId, but the information that the trigger is trying to pull across is not found

Comment: By making the DialId an external identifier on both record types, it seems to work more often.  Ultimately my question remains why this is, and if I can trust it.

Comment: Probably best if you post one example of where the code doesn't work.